# comparision of user account on login page and allowing them to access index page in php

Tags: php

i am developing HRIS WEB APPLICATION for that i have created everything on admin side and employee side. Now i m getting an issue in comparison of both during log in and after it should check whether it  is admin or employee and it should display only that navigation bar that is matching with their permission

Comment: what is the relevant code you tried? edit your post and include it, try to narrow it down to where the problem may be, plus an explanation of what you expected and what happened instead... remember, we are no mind readers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

At the login time you take username, loginid in session variable, right!
Same as just take the user type value to as the session user type, and then based on this user type session you can go for further.
If your are login as admin take user type as admin or else whatever kind of user you are, just take it as user type.
Hope it will work for you.

Comment: thanks it worked comparing user role in session variable